# Pygame return variable from ThreadPool , local variable referenced before assignment with try, except

Tags: python

I'm trying to receive some data from thread, but every time it pass through exception, it not pass inside Try, i don't know what is wrong. I did it once, and i've searched every where. If someone please could help.

```
def receving(name, sock): 
    while run:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            data = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        except:
            pass
        finally:   
            tLock.release()
        return data

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
server = (host,5000)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)


pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
async_result = pool.apply_async(receving, ('arg qualquer', s))
return_val = async_result.get()
print(return_val)

run = True

while run:
    return_val = async_result.get()
    print(return_val)
```

The error message is this:

```
return data
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I've already tried to initialize before try: but the output is the same as default, it jumps Try: same way.
Also tried to make it global but no success.

Comment: I know it isn't running if you copy and paste, but you get what i mean, it's my first quetion and i didn't know how to edit the code here.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you describe is very straight forward. It's all in the function at the top of your code:

```
def receving(name, sock):
    while run:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            data = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        except:
            pass
        finally:   
            tLock.release()
        return data
```

If the code in the `try` block causes an exception, the assignment to `data` won't have run. So when you try to `return data` later on, the local variable has no value and so it doesn't work.

It's not hard to fix that specific issue. Try putting `data = None` or something similar in the `except` clause, instead of just `pass`. That way, `data` will be defined (albeit perhaps with a value that's not very useful) regardless of whether there was an exception or not.

You should however consider tightening up the `except` clause so that you're not ignoring *all* exceptions. That's often a bad idea, since it can cause the program to run even with really broken code in it. For instance, you've never defined `tLock` in the code you've shown, and the `try` would catch the `NameError` caused by trying to acquire it (you'd still get an exception though when the `finally` clause tries to release it, so I'm guessing this isn't a real issue in your code). Normally you should specify the exception types you want to catch. I'm not exactly sure which ones would be normal for your current code, so I'll leave picking them to you.

You might also consider not having an `except` clause at all, if there's no reasonable result to return. That way, the exception would "bubble out" of your function and it would be the caller's responsibility to deal with it. For some kinds of exceptions (e.g. ones cause by programming bugs, not expected situations), this is usually the best way to go.

There's a lot of other weird stuff in your code though, so I'd expect you'll run into other issues after fixing the first one. For instance, you always return from the first iteration of your `while` loop (assuming I fixed your messed up indentation correctly), so there's not really much point in having it at all. If the `return data` line is actually indented less (it's at the same level as `while run`, then the loop will make the code inside run more than once, but it will never stop running since nothing inside it will ever change the value of the global `run` variable.

There may be other issues too, but it's not entirely obvious to me what you're trying to do, so I can't help with those. Multi-threaded code and network programming can be *very* tough to get right even for experienced programmers, so if you're new it might be a better idea to start with something simpler first.